# JavaFX System.setProperty administrator rights

Tags: java, security, javafx, jvm

Do I need administrator rights to use `System.setProperty()` method in JavaFX? I'm really confused reading the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

```
 @exception  SecurityException  if a security manager exists and its
     *             <code>checkPermission</code> method doesn't allow
     *             setting of the specified property.
```

Under what circumstances the JVM disallow me to set the properties ?

If my application is **bundled** JavaFX app is it differs?
Thanks.

Comment: link to the docs that confuse you ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D edited, thanks

Comment: if a security manager exists and its checkPermission method doesn't allow setting of the specified property. If you didnt allow checkPermisson method, you can use this.

What makes you confuse here? Are you using checkPermission?

Comment: The inner method itself uses checkPermission. The question is why it can fail and throw SecurityException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The security manager has nothing to do with operating system permissions defined by having "administrator access".

The security manager is described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/security.html). Note specifically:

> A *security manager* is an object that defines a security policy for an application. This policy specifies actions that are unsafe or sensitive. Any actions not allowed by the security policy cause a `SecurityException` to be thrown.

and

> Typically, a web applet runs with a security manager provided by the browser or Java Web Start plugin. Other kinds of applications normally run without a security manager, unless the application itself defines one. If no security manager is present, the application has no security policy and acts without restrictions.

So an application running under web start will have a security manager which allows actions configured by the JNLP file (and will only allow elevated actions for signed applications).

Unless you go to some lengths to change this, a stand-alone application running as a "normal" desktop application will not have a security manager, and its actions will not be restricted. In particular, if there is no security manager, then according to the documentation you cite:

```
@exception  SecurityException  if a security manager exists and its
     *             <code>checkPermission</code> method doesn't allow
     *             setting of the specified property.
```

no `SecurityException` will be thrown.